# Named Pipes Provider, error: 40

Tags: sql-server

I have a sql server and i can connect it with sa login from ip 192.168.2.18
When i try to connect my sqlserver from outside i write my internet ip and forwarded the 1433 port to 192.168.2.18. 
I can connect my sql server with my local ip only without writing any server name or instance name.
I tried to connect outside by ip only or ip\instance or ip\server\instance but not in any case i can log in.

When i try to log in with ip only i get this error

```
 ------------------------------
    ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. 
The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. 
(provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 53)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=53&LinkId=20476
```

When i try to log in ip\instance or ip\server\instance i get this error

```
------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. 
The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. 
(provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: -1)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=-1&LinkId=20476
```

Where is the wrong thing?

- Named pipes/TCP is enabled.
- Remote connections are allowed in instance
- Windows Firewall is off
- Sql port is forwarded to the server from the router

I am connecting to sql in localhost as; Server Name: SAMSUNG Login: sa Password: ***** this works perfect

I am connecting to sql in same domain as; Server Name: 192.168.2.18 Login: sa Password: ****** this works perfect

So i try to connect my sql from internet as; Server Name: 144.122.180.147 Login: sa Password: ****** this does not work. Can you say if my server name is right or i need to change it?

Comment: Doesn't use of a numeric IP address in a Connection String force use of the TCP protocol over Named Pipes?

Answer (score 0):

[This link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/2a8f2e64-74cf-46f2-b2be-bbb08b1502cb/re-named-pipes-provider-error-40-could-not-open-a-connection-to-sql-server?forum=sqlreportingservices) has a list of possible problems that would return these results.

More often than not, `Named Pipes` was not enabled on your instance.

Comment: - Named pipes/TCP is enabled.
- Remote connections are allowed in instance
- Windows Firewall is off
- Sql port is forwarded to the server from the router